# Trying to get property 'user_role' of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to access this page that is going to show me login form that is going to have various users.
But when I'm Loading this page it takes me to the that page but this error message ("Trying to get property 'user_role' of non-object") is popping up

In my Controller code I have tried using this method $userRole['user_rule'] instead $user->user_rule it works for me but in next page I got this Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

> Filename: C:\wamp64\www\hms-1\application\controllers\general.php
>
> Line Number: 41

This My Controller code general.php

```
class General extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
    $this->load->model('general_model');



}

public function variable(){
    $this->data['companyInfo'] = $this->general_model->companyInfo();
    $this->data['userInfo'] = $this->general_model->getUserLoggedIn($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['UserTitles'] = $this->general_model->UserTitles();
    $this->data['gender'] = $this->general_model->gender();
    $this->data['civilStatus'] = $this->general_model->civilStatus();
    $this->data['departmentList'] = $this->general_model->departmentList();
    $this->data['designationList'] = $this->general_model->designationList();
    $this->data['userRoleList'] = $this->general_model->userRoleList();
    $this->data['roomTypeList'] = $this->general_model->roomTypeList();
    $this->data['floorList'] = $this->general_model->floorList();
    $this->data['roomMasterList'] = $this->general_model->roomMasterList();
    $this->data['bloodGroup'] = $this->general_model->bloodGroup();
    $this->data['religionList'] = $this->general_model->religionList();
    $this->data['doctorList'] = $this->general_model->doctorList();
    $this->data['doctorList2'] = $this->general_model->doctorList();
    $this->data['insuranceCompList'] = $this->general_model->insuranceCompList();
    $this->data['patientListRows'] = $this->general_model->patientList();





    // Sidebar menu restriction access
    $userRole = $this->general_model->getUserLoggedIn($this->session->userdata('username'));
    // var_dump($userRole);
    // Dashboard 
    $this->data['hasAccesstoDoctorAvail'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("134",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;

    // Billing Module Validation
    $this->data['hasAccesstoBilling'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("85",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoPOS'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("84",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoSurgical'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("116",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;

    // Patient Appointment
    $this->data['hasAccesstoAppointment'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("121",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoAddAppointment'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("122",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;

    // Patient Management
    $this->data['hasAccesstoPatient'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("49",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoAddPatient'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("48",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoPatient'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("49",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoOPDRegistration'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("91",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoOPDEnquiry'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("92",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoIPDRegistration'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("93",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->data['hasAccesstoIPDEnquiry'] = ($this->has_rights_to_access("94",$userRole['user_role']) == FALSE) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

general_model.php
    class General_model extends CI_Model{

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
}

public function companyInfo(){
    $query = $this->db->get("company_info");
    return $query->row();
}

public function getUserLoggedIn($username){
    $this->db->select("A.user_id, A.lastname, A.firstname, A.middlename, A.picture, B.designation,A.user_role,C.module,
            D.department_id");
    $this->db->where('A.username', $username);
    $this->db->join("designation B","B.designation_id = A.designation","left outer");
    $this->db->join("user_roles C","C.role_id = A.user_role","left outer");
    $this->db->join("department D","D.department_id = A.department","left outer");
    $query = $this->db->get("users A");
    return $query->row("");
}
```

I wanted to solve this error and load my dashboard, please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your object ($userRole) not included (user_rule).
First get count from Object like this : count($userRole).
Second better use isset for check your object like this : isset($userRole['user_rule'])